# Unable to find a way to store this scraped data in such a way that i can access it later with the help of a simple loop?

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-structures, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape all the upcoming event details from an institution:-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("http://www.iitg.ac.in/home/eventsall/events")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")
cards = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "newsarea"})

iitg_title = []
iitg_date = []
iitg_link = []
for card in cards[0:6]:
    iitg_date.append(card.find("div", attrs={"class": "ndate"}).text)
    iitg_title.append(card.find("div", attrs={"class": "ntitle"}).text.strip())
    iitg_link.append(card.find("div", attrs={"class": "ntitle"}).a['href'])

print("Upcoming event details scraped from iitg website:- \n")
for i in range(len(iitg_title)):
    print("Title:- ", iitg_title[i])
    print("Dates:- ", iitg_date[i])
    print("Link:- ", iitg_link[i])
    print('\n')
```

And the above code fetched me these details:-

```
Upcoming event details scraped from iitg website:- 

Title:-  4 batch for the certification programme on AI & ML by Eckovation in association with E&ICT Academy IIT Guwahati
Dates:-  15 Aug 2020 - 15 Aug 2020
Link:-  http://eict.iitg.ac.in/online_courses_training.html


Title:-  8th International and 47th National conference on Fluid Mechanics and Fluid Power
Dates:-  09 Dec 2020 - 11 Dec 2020
Link:-  https://event.iitg.ac.in/fmfp2020/


Title:-  4 months Internship programme on VLSI Circuit Design
Dates:-  10 Aug 2020 - 10 Dec 2020
Link:-  http://eict.iitg.ac.in/online_courses_training.html


Title:-  6 week Training cum Internship programme on AI & ML under TEQIP-III orgainsed by Assam Science Technology University
Dates:-  10 Aug 2020 - 20 Sep 2020
Link:-  http://eict.iitg.ac.in/online_courses_training.html


Title:-  6 week Training cum Internship programme on Industry 4.0 (Industrial IoT) under TEQIP-III orgainsed by Assam Science Technology University
Dates:-  10 Aug 2020 - 20 Sep 2020
Link:-  http://eict.iitg.ac.in/online_courses_training.html


Title:-  6 week Training cum Internship programme on Robotics Fundamentals under TEQIP-III orgainsed by Assam Science Technology University
Dates:-  10 Aug 2020 - 20 Sep 2020
Link:-  http://eict.iitg.ac.in/online_courses_training.html
```

Now since from past five hours's I have been messing around my head to be able to store my results in such a way that I can access it later with a simple for loop.
**How can I make this possible?**

Comment: You mean like writing to a file?

Comment: May be you would like to save the list of those events with `pickle` library?

Comment: No no, I don't want to write this data to an external file, I tried that approach too but that didn't suit me for some reason, I just need to store the values of these three variables into a single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use, for example [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html) module to write the data to disk:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("http://www.iitg.ac.in/home/eventsall/events")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")
cards = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "newsarea"})

events = []
for card in cards[0:6]:
    events.append((
        card.find("div", attrs={"class": "ntitle"}).text.strip(),
        card.find("div", attrs={"class": "ndate"}).text,
        card.find("div", attrs={"class": "ntitle"}).a['href']
    ))

# save data:
with open('data.json', 'w') as f_out:
    json.dump(events, f_out)

# ...

# load data back:
with open('data.json', 'r') as f_in:
    events = json.load(f_in)

print("Upcoming event details scraped from iitg website:- \n")
for t, d, l in events:
    print("Title:- ", t)
    print("Dates:- ", d)
    print("Link:- ", l)
    print('\n')
```

Prints:

```
Upcoming event details scraped from iitg website:- 

Title:-  4 batch for the certification programme on AI & ML by Eckovation in association with E&ICT Academy IIT Guwahati
Dates:-  15 Aug 2020 - 15 Aug 2020
Link:-  http://eict.iitg.ac.in/online_courses_training.html


Title:-  8th International and 47th National conference on Fluid Mechanics and Fluid Power
Dates:-  09 Dec 2020 - 11 Dec 2020
Link:-  https://event.iitg.ac.in/fmfp2020/


Title:-  4 months Internship programme on VLSI Circuit Design
Dates:-  10 Aug 2020 - 10 Dec 2020
Link:-  http://eict.iitg.ac.in/online_courses_training.html


Title:-  6 week Training cum Internship programme on AI & ML under TEQIP-III orgainsed by Assam Science Technology University
Dates:-  10 Aug 2020 - 20 Sep 2020
Link:-  http://eict.iitg.ac.in/online_courses_training.html


Title:-  6 week Training cum Internship programme on Industry 4.0 (Industrial IoT) under TEQIP-III orgainsed by Assam Science Technology University
Dates:-  10 Aug 2020 - 20 Sep 2020
Link:-  http://eict.iitg.ac.in/online_courses_training.html


Title:-  6 week Training cum Internship programme on Robotics Fundamentals under TEQIP-III orgainsed by Assam Science Technology University
Dates:-  10 Aug 2020 - 20 Sep 2020
Link:-  http://eict.iitg.ac.in/online_courses_training.html
```

Comment: Can't this problem be solved without writing the data in any new file?